# Firebase dynamic link not returning deeplink iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an app integrated with firebase dynamic links. I'm having a weird issue, I'm only able to retrieve deeplink from dynamic link when I'm in debugging mode. The rest of the time  it just return me deep link = nil and error = nil. Does anyone run into this issue?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity: (NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {

BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (dynamicLink && dynamicLink.url) {
        if (self.shouldReload) {
            [[EPLAppConfiguration sharedInstance] saveUniversalLinkUrl:dynamicLink.url.absoluteString];
        } else {
            [[EPLLinkManager sharedInstance] universalLinkTriggered:dynamicLink.url];
        }
    }
}];
[FIRDynamicLinks performDiagnosticsWithCompletion:nil];
return handled;
```

}